# Heroku - Uninitialized constant for importing a module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I have a module

```
lib/Basicstats.rb   (module Basicstats ...etc. end)
```

I am importing this into a model

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
    include Basicstats
    #additional class code etc.
end
```

I `grep`-d for the module and 'Basicstats' is only referenced in `Basicstats.rb` and `app/model/vote.rb`.

This works fine for my local development.  But during my Heroku deployment I am getting this error and it can't seem to recognize the module?  (I'm also curious how this is working in my local development without a require anywhere.)

```
2015-03-28T22:19:52.714077+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/app/models/vote.rb:16:in `<class:Vote>': uninitialized constant Basicstats (NameError)
```

Comment: Where is the module being `require`-d? Any chance it's happening in config/environments/development.rb?

Comment: Good question, was hoping that would be it.  But `grep`-d for the module 'Basicstats' and only found the include (and use) in Vote model, and in module definition.  Original post updated.

Comment: In that case, you might want to try adding an initializer that requires it.

Comment: Bingo, didn't completely understand the Rails convention for loading from `lib/` and decided to use the auto loading feature where subfolder name matches module name.  Thanks and wish I could mark your comment as the Accepted Answer.

Comment: My pleasure! I'll add a proper answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your module isn't being explicitly required or auto-loaded by Rails (this will/won't happen depending which version of Rails you're using and how `config.autoload_paths` is configured).

Your best bet is to add an initializer which explicitly requires your module:

```
# config/initializers/basicstats.rb

require Rails.root.join('lib/basicstats')
```